# Google Analytics Transactional Events from Server

Tags: c#, google-tag-manager

We are using Google Tag Manager to capture events happening on the website. That works well.
If for example a user purchases a subscription, Google Tag Manager captures the transaction from the Order Success Page and sends it over to Google Analytics.

The subscription is now managed in a third party payment processor. Once they renew the subscription, it would send a webhook call to our server and we would execute logic to extend the subscription server side and inform user and so on.

The question is: How can we now send this renewal event to Google Analytics since all of this happens server side?

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use measurement protocol for GA4.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events?client_type=firebase

When in the server side get payment data you should send "purchase" event in Analytics.